# JQuery mouseleave function snaps back instead of transitioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Instead of transitioning slowly back into a div without a border radius it snaps back.

I've tried changing border radius property but it did the same thing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#thesun").mouseenter(function() {
$("#thesun").animate({
  "border-radius": "50%",
}, 500);
});
$("#thesun").mouseleave(function() {
$("#thesun").animate({
  "border-radius": "0%",
}, 500);
});
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Filizof/pen/mvPMEX)

Comment: Here is the project: https://codepen.io/Filizof/pen/mvPMEX?editors=1010

Comment: `I've tried changing border radius` can you explain what exactly you want

Comment: Solution below. But the answer to "why" is: because the animation starts at 0 instead of the current value. If you set the border-radius to 25% in the css (or in the html), then you'll see that the animation for mouseenter snaps to 0 before starting the animation to 50%.

Comment: I was hoping I could maybe a smooth transition but apparently that's impossible. I'll continue searching for a solution, surely there's a way for it to transition back without starting at a value of 0, even when I changed a border radius to 25% it still snapped back.

Comment: @Fico You have read לבני מלכה's answer, right?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with only css and [`transition`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) on `#thesun:hover`

```css
.planets {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#thesun {
  height: 400px;
  width: 412px;
  background: gold;
  position: relative;
  left: 260px;
  text-align: center;
   transition: border-radius 0.5s; /* add this */
}
#thesun:hover{ /* and add this */
 border-radius:50%;
}
#theearth {
  background: #008080;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  left: 340px;
  text-align: center;
}
#solardiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.labels {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:
 -1px -1px 0 #000,
 1px -1px 0 #000,
 -1px 1px 0 #000,
 1px 1px 0 #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  display: inline-block;
}
body {
  background-image: url("https://hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/nebula-space-scenery-4k-q4.jpg");
  
}
```

```html
<div id="solardiv">
  <div id="thesun"><p class="labels">SUN</p></div>
</div>
```